# When should you move saplings from part shade into full sun?

Tags: transplanting

I received my trees from the mail order catalog less than a week ago, and they're "leafing" very quickly. When should I generally move them into full sun to help them regenerate their sugars?

Comment: Where are they now? In pots, bags?

Comment: 'move them into full sun to help them regenerate their sugars'??  The most common way plants are able to make food FOR THEMSELVES is by producing photosynthetic vegetative growth and getting plenty of sun (there are other ways some plants get energy to grow and multiply such as; mushroom / fungus plants, epiphyte, parasite, saprophytes). 'Leafing out' is a good thing, shows they are alive.  As long as they've been outside and used to being outside get them in the sun!!  What do you mean by regenerating sugars?  Are these plants in the garden or are they in pots?

Comment: They're in pots, and worry they're not ready to be put in almost full sun, since it's not fully recovered from travel shock yet.

Comment: Didn't you get bare roots plants? So you put them in pots first?

Comment: @Stephie yes they were, yes

Comment: Are you planning to keep them in pots? Or was your plan to put them in the ground?

Comment: put them in the ground once they're big enough to easily not mow.

Comment: What species are we discussing here? And where are you located? Both of these items will factor into an answer

Comment: MN, and a general rule of thumb for saplings that have buds, small leaves, et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare rooted trees are normally planted at the end of winter or early spring before they break dormancy. I presume that you planted them into pots, and they woke up at the same time.

Since plant shock is mainly from transpirational moisture loss from leaves, and you don't have much in the way of leaves now, they can go into full sun now if it's appropriate for that tree. In the same way you plant into the ground bare root, you don't shift them to a sunnier location later on as the gradual change in light levels and temperature allows the tree to adapt.